# Convert object type in Series to datetime format

Tags: datetime, object, series

I'm new to Python and stuck with the following problem. I have a column in my data set having dtype object with the following format: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SjHH.png)

I'm stuck with converting the values in this column to datetime format as I get error messages each time I try something out. Can anyone help me with how to get this done?

Thanks!

Comment: Tried [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)?

Comment: What is the error message that you're getting?